# Python Print List Elements with Defined Range

Tags: python, list, range

I have a list that is a column of numbers in a df called "doylist" for day of year list. I need to figure out how to print a range of user-defined rows in ascending order from the doylist df. For example, let's say I need to print the last daysback=60 days in the list from today's day of year to daysforward = 19 days from today's day of year. So, if today's day of year is 47, then my new list would look like this ranging from day of year 352 to day of year 67.

day_of_year =

```
day_of_year = (today - datetime.datetime(today.year, 1, 1)).days + 1
```

doylist =

```
doylist
Out[106]: 
     dyofyr
0         1
1         2
2         3
3         4
4         5
5         6
6         7
7         8
8         9
9        10
10       11
11       12
12       13
13       14
14       15
15       16
16       17
17       18
18       19
19       20
20       21
21       22
22       23
23       24
24       25
25       26
26       27
27       28
28       29
29       30
30       31
31       32
32       33
33       34
34       35
35       36
36       37
37       38
38       39
39       40
40       41
41       42
42       43
43       44
44       45
45       46
46       47
47       48
48       49
49       50
50       51
51       52
52       53
53       54
54       55
55       56
56       57
57       58
58       59
59       60
60       61
61       62
62       63
63       64
64       65
65       66
66       67
67       68
68       69
69       70
70       71
71       72
72       73
73       74
74       75
75       76
76       77
77       78
78       79
79       80
80       81
81       82
82       83
83       84
84       85
85       86
86       87
87       88
88       89
89       90
90       91
91       92
92       93
93       94
94       95
95       96
96       97
97       98
98       99
99      100
100     101
101     102
102     103
103     104
104     105
105     106
106     107
107     108
108     109
109     110
110     111
111     112
112     113
113     114
114     115
115     116
116     117
117     118
118     119
119     120
120     121
121     122
122     123
123     124
124     125
125     126
126     127
127     128
128     129
129     130
130     131
131     132
132     133
133     134
134     135
135     136
136     137
137     138
138     139
139     140
140     141
141     142
142     143
143     144
144     145
145     146
146     147
147     148
148     149
149     150
150     151
151     152
152     153
153     154
154     155
155     156
156     157
157     158
158     159
159     160
160     161
161     162
162     163
163     164
164     165
165     166
166     167
167     168
168     169
169     170
170     171
171     172
172     173
173     174
174     175
175     176
176     177
177     178
178     179
179     180
180     181
181     182
182     183
183     184
184     185
185     186
186     187
187     188
188     189
189     190
190     191
191     192
192     193
193     194
194     195
195     196
196     197
197     198
198     199
199     200
200     201
201     202
202     203
203     204
204     205
205     206
206     207
207     208
208     209
209     210
210     211
211     212
212     213
213     214
214     215
215     216
216     217
217     218
218     219
219     220
220     221
221     222
222     223
223     224
224     225
225     226
226     227
227     228
228     229
229     230
230     231
231     232
232     233
233     234
234     235
235     236
236     237
237     238
238     239
239     240
240     241
241     242
242     243
243     244
244     245
245     246
246     247
247     248
248     249
249     250
250     251
251     252
252     253
253     254
254     255
255     256
256     257
257     258
258     259
259     260
260     261
261     262
262     263
263     264
264     265
265     266
266     267
267     268
268     269
269     270
270     271
271     272
272     273
273     274
274     275
275     276
276     277
277     278
278     279
279     280
280     281
281     282
282     283
283     284
284     285
285     286
286     287
287     288
288     289
289     290
290     291
291     292
292     293
293     294
294     295
295     296
296     297
297     298
298     299
299     300
300     301
301     302
302     303
303     304
304     305
305     306
306     307
307     308
308     309
309     310
310     311
311     312
312     313
313     314
314     315
315     316
316     317
317     318
318     319
319     320
320     321
321     322
322     323
323     324
324     325
325     326
326     327
327     328
328     329
329     330
330     331
331     332
332     333
333     334
334     335
335     336
336     337
337     338
338     339
339     340
340     341
341     342
342     343
343     344
344     345
345     346
346     347
347     348
348     349
349     350
350     351
351     352
352     353
353     354
354     355
355     356
356     357
357     358
358     359
359     360
360     361
361     362
362     363
363     364
364     365

daysback = doylist.iloc[day_of_year-61] # 60 days back from today
daysforward = doylist.iloc[day_of_year+19] # 20 days forward from today
```

I need my final df or list to look like this:
final_list =

```
352
353
354
355
356
357
358
359
360
361
362
363
364
365
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
```

I have tried variations of this but get the following error using this with a df called "doylist"-thank you!

```
finallist = list(range(doylist.iloc[day_of_year-61],doylist.iloc[day_of_year+19]))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[113], line 1
    finallist = list(range(doylist.iloc[day_of_year-61],doylist.iloc[day_of_year+19]))

TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand why you are using a dataframe to do this. This could be done with a simple list and modulus.

```
def days_between_forward_back(day_of_year, days_since, days_forward):
    doylist = [x + 1 for x in range(365)]
    lower_index = (day_of_year - days_since - 1) % 365
    upper_index = day_of_year + days_forward
    assert upper_index < 365
    if lower_index > upper_index:
        result = doylist[lower_index:]
        result.extend(doylist[:upper_index])
        return result
    else:
        return doylist[lower_index:upper_index]


days = days_between_forward_back(47, 60, 20)
print(f"For day of year 47, 60 days before, 20 days ahead, days are {days}")


days = days_between_forward_back(300, 61, 10)
print(f"For day of year 300, 61 days before, 10 days ahead, days are {days}")
```

Handling the case where both days_since and days_forward will move us to another year is left as an exercise for the asker.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you :

```py
import datetime

this_date = datetime.datetime.now()

how_many_dayes_do_you_want_to_go_back = 80


how_many_dayes_in_each_munth = {1:31
                                ,2:28
                                ,3:31
                                ,4:30
                                ,5:31
                                ,6:30
                                ,7:31
                                ,8:31
                                ,9:30
                                ,10:31
                                ,11:30
                                ,12:31}


dayes_in_this_year = 0


for i in range(1,this_date.month+1):
    dayes_in_this_year += how_many_dayes_in_each_munth.get(i)


if how_many_dayes_do_you_want_to_go_back % dayes_in_this_year == how_many_dayes_do_you_want_to_go_back and how_many_dayes_do_you_want_to_go_back < dayes_in_this_year:
    for i in range(dayes_in_this_year-how_many_dayes_do_you_want_to_go_back,dayes_in_this_year+1):
        print(i)
else:
    the_rest_to_the_last_year = how_many_dayes_do_you_want_to_go_back - dayes_in_this_year

    for i in range(365-the_rest_to_the_last_year,366):
        print(i)

    for i in range(dayes_in_this_year+1):
        print(i)
```

and yes , you know you can improve the code to use it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're getting hung up while converting back and forth between data formats of `int`, `datetime` etc... This type of error is much easier to keep track of and fix if you utilize python's new-ish type hinting to make sure you're being careful with data types. To that end it is also useful to keep using `datetime` as much as possible to take better advantage of the library (so you don't have to keep track of things like leap years etc. on your own). I wrote a few functions to help you convert:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def dt_from_doy(year: int, doy: int) -> datetime:
    #useful if you need to use doy from your dataframe to get datetime.
    #if you can convert the input to be a datetime in the first place that
    #might be even better (fewer conversions of data type)
    return datetime.strptime("{:04d}-{:03d}".format(year, doy), "%Y-%j")

def doy_from_dt(dt: datetime) -> int:
    #used in the example below
    return int(dt.strftime("%j"))

#example

today = datetime(2023,2,16)

list_of_dt = [today + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(-20,20)]

list_of_doy = [doy_from_dt(dt) for dt in list_of_dt]
```